# How to select a string from a variable using grep or awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a variable which has content like

```
----- File | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s ----------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- All files | 36.95 | 20.87 | 24.
```

PS: The output I mentioned is actually pretty long and I trimmed it for the sake of posting here. I found out by trial and error that All files <> | was between position 970-990

I am trying to extract the value associated with All files i.e 36.95. I am able to use cut to get the substring like this

```
TOTAL="$(cut -c 975-990 <<< $RES)"
```

But I am looking for better approach for example using a regex pattern, I saw patterns like grep and awk but I am not able to formulate it.

Comment: The cut code you show cannot be producing an output of "36.95" with the content you show (it would be `cut -c 499-504`). What does it mean for a value to be "associated with All files"? Do you mean the `|`-delimited field following it?

Comment: It is actually a pretty long output, I happened to trim it out.

Comment: "36.95" has 5 characters, not 930, so it still couldn't be correct. You have left out important information for creating a robust solution.

Comment: I am trying to gather the test coverage from an npm test command

Comment: Unless you have a **specific technical reason**, don't specify things like "using grep or awk" -- let the person answering choose the best tools for the job. Often, a shell builtin is faster than _any_ external tool.

Comment: I'd suggest you provide the raw output from the `npm` command since parsing *that* output may be easier/more-reliable than trying to (re)parse the contents of the `RES` variable

Comment: Given I now notice you use `$RES` unquoted in your question I suspect you're using it unquoted to show it's contents in your question, `echo $RES`, and it in fact DOES contain newlines but by not quoting the variable you're stripping them, Please [edit] your question to show the output of `echo "$RES"` (i.e. with quotes to retain the original content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not limiting yourself to `cut`, this is a possible answer using `sed` that looks for the `All files | ... |` pattern and grabs the text from there.

```bash
TOTAL="$(sed -E 's/^.* All files \| ([^ ]+) \| .*$/\1/' <<< $RES)"
```

Here's a tiny script with that idea put to use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

RES="----- File | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s ----------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- All files | 36.95 | 20.87 | 24."
TOTAL="$(sed -E 's/^.* All files \| ([^ ]+) \| .*$/\1/' <<< $RES)"
echo "$TOTAL"
```

Running that:

```
$ ./test.sh
36.95
```

Comment: I like this idea, the only problem is that it does not echo anything, I beleive that it is undefined

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

The `sed` command will output the relevant output, and that will be captured in the `TOTAL` variable. If you want to echo that, just `echo "$TOTAL"`?

Comment: I think I am wrong, just plain echoing it returns the value 36.95, however if I assign it to a variable and echo it does not print anything

Comment: I have been trying to run the above command in my gitlab shell which seems to use gnu runner which is why although this command works like a charm on my local(macbook) it just wont execute it and instead returns me the value of $RES from the above answer instead of TOTAL. What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

And since you mentioned it - here an `awk` alternative:

```
total=$(awk -F'|' '{print $12}'<<<"${res}")
```

Note: all uppercase variable names are (more by convention than anything) reserved for the system.

Comment: It's more than convention. For example: [The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08) - implying use of ones **not** containing lowercase may affect operation of "utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2017"

Answer (score 1):

Since `RES` is a shell variable, you could do something like this:

```
TOTAL="${RES#*All Files}"
TOTAL="${TOTAL#*|}"
TOTAL="${TOTAL%|*}"
TOTAL="${TOTAL// /}"
```

- The first line removes everything up to and including the words All Files
- Since it is unsure how many spaces are after the words All Files, we remove again everything upto the first <pipe>-character
- Finally, we remove everything after the first <pipe>-character.
- As a final step, we delete all spaces

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your `RES` variable contents are all on 1 line, I think you're making it look that way by using `echo $RES` instead of `echo "$RES"` and what it really contains looks more like:

```
$ echo "$RES"
----------
  File    | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------
All files |  36.95  |   20.87  | 24.
```

in which case all you need is:

```
$ echo "$RES" | awk -F' *[|] *' '/All files/{print $2}'
36.95
```